# Unable to change system and nautilus icons in Ubuntu 14.04 and Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: unity, themes, icons

I have been experimenting with new themes provided by noobslab.com, and I am having issues applying all parts. It seems the only icons I can set are Ubuntu's default, anything else gives me blank pages, as shown below:

[image: Nautilus with no icons]

To give and example, I used apt-get to install the azure theme. Once installed, the theme is available through the Unity Tweak Tool. Once clicked, the theme applies to windowing and the launch bar. In all cases the icons have to be changed manually using the tweak tool, however, the problem described previously always happens (only default icons work). Has anyone experienced this? Is there another tool I can use to get the job done? Thanks to all that reply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a little more detail. E.g. an example theme you've used, how you unpacked and set up the theme and what all steps you took to apply it. Some of this can be conferred from the image but it works better if we have solid facts to go on :)

Comment: Hi Seth, I added some additional details as suggested. Hopefully the problem comes across a little more clearer.